# File.browseForSave() on iOS

Tags: ios, flash, air

I'm porting AIR app to iOS. App saves document localy with `File.browseForSave()`. That seem not to to work on iPad. How is it possible to save files on iPad?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may already noticed browsing file on an iOS device is restricted.

To save the file at a location on the device try using File.applicationStorageDirectory

See also:

- [Opening a File Dialog Box when button is tapped in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010606/opening-a-file-dialog-box-when-button-is-tapped-in-iphone)

Comment: no, browsing is never allowed on iOS no matter if you use xCode or AIR