# File.browseForSave() on ipad

Tags: ios, flash, air

I'm porting AIR app to iOS. App saves document localy with `File.browseForSave()`. That seem not to to work on iPad. How is it possible to save files on iPad?

P.S. tracing `File.url` says "app-storage:/New%20map.comap". Maybe names with % are not allowed on iOS?

Best wishes

Comment: This is not possible on iOS!

This is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374077/file-browseforsave-on-ios/9375371#9375371

Comment: Yep, I know. My coworker opened previous question, but an advice didn't help.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Which advice did not worked ? there was no advice... Just BrowseForSave is not allowed on ios. you can still save on a path without browsing, but only on the right folder with the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only save to specific directories within the apps sandboxed area. e.g. Documents directory.

Something like this saves an image to the documents directory. It uses the Adobe JPGEncoder to create a byte array that is written and the crop method to take a snapshot of the stage.

```
private function createImages():void {

    var snapShot:Bitmap = crop(0, 0, 1024, 768);

    f = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.jpg"); 

    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);                                         

    var j:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes = j.encode(snapShot.bitmapData);

    stream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.bytesAvailable);
    stream.close();

    stream.openAsync(f, FileMode.READ); 
    stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imagewritten, false, 0, true);   


}

private function imagewritten(e:Event):void {
trace("done");
}



private function crop( _x:Number, _y:Number, _width:Number, _height:Number, displayObject:DisplayObject = null):Bitmap
{

var cropArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, _width, _height );

var croppedBitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData( _width, _height ), PixelSnapping.ALWAYS, true );

croppedBitmap.bitmapData.draw( (displayObject!=null) ? displayObject : stage, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -_x, -_y) , null, null, cropArea, true );

cropArea = null;

return croppedBitmap;
}
```