# Opening a File Dialog Box when button is tapped in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, file, button, dialog

I did a cocoa application in which the file dialog box is opening when a button is tapped with the use of NSOpenPanel controller in cocoa applications.For ipad applications we are using UISplitViewController.

I want to know that for developing the applications in iphone,what controller to be used for opening a file dialog box when a button is tapped.

For example in composing a mail.In composing a mail,if we want to attach any files from the local drive,we click the "Attach a File" button. Then it will opens a file open dialog box for selection of file what we want.

Can any one help me or suggest me what controller to be used for opening a file in iphone applications?For opening a file dialog box ,in

cocoa applications --------- Controller used is  NSOpenPanel

ipad  applications --------- Controller used is UISplitViewController

Like wise for i phone applications ------- ??????

Please help me out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a concept of browsing arbitrary local files.

It does have the ability to browse for images from the photo library — for that you can use `UIImagePickerController`.

Other than photos, the only files you can even open are ones that are inside your own sandbox folder (i.e. ones that you've put there yourself). There isn't a built in view controller that will display them — you'd have to write your own that will read the list of files using something like `NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`, and display them in an appropriate UI.